# Getting NullPointerExceptionat Fragment commit

Tags: android, android-fragments

I do a transition of a fragment in the same container. But sometimes it gives NullPointerException at fragment commit. Below is my method which gives an error.

```
public void goToMapFragment() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Const.Tag.MAP_FRAGMENT) == null) {
        MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in_out,
                    R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.fade_in_out,
                    R.anim.slide_out_right);
        ft.replace(R.id.contain_frame, mapFragment, Const.Tag.MAP_FRAGMENT);

        //Here gives NullPointerException.....
        ft.commitNowAllowingStateLoss();    
    }
}
```

Please provide a solution which you have.

Below I attach stack trace of it.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:1959)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1980)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:626)
at com.gogo.MainDrawerActivity.goToMapFragment(MainDrawerActivity.java:392)
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: I attach stack trace of it. Please find it.

Comment: Please refer [This Medium link](https://medium.com/inloop/demystifying-androids-commitallowingstateloss-cb9011a544cc) and [This link](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) to learn more about fragment transactions and when each method should be used